# Radio button is not checked dynamically in php

Tags: php, html

When I inspect radio button (right side) I can see that is **checked**.
However radio button (left side) is **not cheched**.
I have red set **autocomplete='off'**, but did not help.
[image: Radio button]

```
<label class="cursorPointer ml0px <?php echo $ml15px;?>">
<Input type = 'Radio' Name ='vyber_tb' class="prepinac cursorPointer" value='<?php echo $db_hod;?>' <?php echo ($nazov_db == $db_hod) ? "checked='checked'" : "";?> autocomplete="off">
<?php echo $db_hod;
if($page == "home"){
echo " <span>".$maxWords."</span> / <span>".$have_words[0]."</span>";
}
?>
</label>
```

**The problem is solved.**
There are more Radio buttons same value and name, however they are `display:none;`. I did not know that `display:none` may affect the result.

Comment: Can you show the PHP code which is used to generate this part of the HTML.  It may show some issues which are difficult to tell from screen shots.

Comment: Most probably PHP has some issues, remove php from <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='vyber_tb'>  and recheck it. This will confirm which part causing problem, PHP or HTML

Comment: Also follow standards. Use either single or double quotes(I recommend double quotes for HTML and single quotes for PHP) for HTML and PHP, and follow it throughout your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try out just **checked**

```
<input type="radio" id="drone" name="drone" value="drone" checked>
```

Answer (score 0):

Else clause in echo is redundant. Checkout this code:

```
<Input type="radio" name="vyber_tb" class="prepinac cursorPointer" value="<?php echo $db_hod;?>" <?php if($nazov_db == $db_hod) echo 'checked';?>>
```

Always follow standards. Use either single or double quotes(I recommend double quotes for HTML and single quotes for PHP) for HTML and PHP, and follow it throughout your code. Look how much readable is the above code compared to your code.

In standard HTML `checked` is a standalone attribute which could be used with `<input type="checkbox">` and `<input type="radio">`. Though browsers support all these variations of checked:

```
checked
checked = "true"
checked = "checked"
```

only the first one is recommended by W3C.
Source: [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp)

Also the `autocomplete` attribute works with the following  types: text, search, url, tel, email, password, datepickers, range, and color.
Source: [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp)

Also whenever possible use single quotes (') with php. Using 'Single quoted' strings is more efficient as the contents of the string displayed "as is". Variables and escape sequences except `\\` will not be interpreted. Which makes them lot more efficient than "Double quoted" strings.